# RavenDB Updated Class new property not getting serialised

Tags: ravendb

I am working with RavenDb and am stuck at a brick wall.

I had an old class that I was persisting and it was all working fine. But during development I added an additional property to this class. Now when I persist the class all the old properties get persisted but the new property added is not appearing when I brows the repository using web browser.

Is there anything specific that needs to be done if the class changes for raven to serialise this new property?

I am on version 426.

Comment: Can you post your class definition?

Comment: Following your questions I just realised that the class is not POCO. It has a serialisable attribute with all properties that are getting serialised marked as [DataMember]. I will try clearing this and post if this is causing serialisation not to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User544550,
If you have [DataMember] properties, it will use those and ignore anything not marked with [DataMember]
Either remove all [DataMember] attributes, or add [DataMember] to the new prop.