# RavenDB SaveChanges() not saving properties on derived class ([DataMember] used in other class)

Tags: ravendb

I've recently upgraded to build 2230, and things are working just fine. However, I just updated the RavenDB .NET client assemblies and now I'm having this issue.

This code has been in place for a year or so. This is how I'm saving:

```
public void Save(EntityBase objectToSave)
{
    using (IDocumentSession session = GetOptimisticSession())
    {
        session.Store(objectToSave, objectToSave.Etag);
        session.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And this is the object I'm saving.

```
public class InstallationEnvironment : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LogicalOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Now the base class:

```
public class EntityBase : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    public string Id { get; set; }  // Required field for all objects with RavenDB.
}
```

The problem is that the base class property (Id) is getting persisted in RavenDB, but the derived properties (Name, LogicalOrder) are not.

Why would only the base class properties be saved in RavenDB?

Comment: Do you mean `2330` which is the latest stable?  And are both client and server on the save version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. Through trial and error, I noticed that *one* derived property was being saved (on a different class than the one shown in my question), and that property was decorated with the `[DataMember]` attribute. I just recently added it because I'm creating a WCF service for my app, and I started by using that attribute on one property for testing.

As Ayende states [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6986324/279516), you have to use `[DataMember]` on all properties, or on none of them. If `[DataMember]` exists on a property, all others will be ignored.

Note: This was a problem for me even though `[DataMember]` was specified on a *property in a different class*. It seems like if I use `[DataMember]` anywhere, I have to use it for everything.

Comment: Any idea why RavenDB would work that way? This was a tricky problem to figure out.

Comment: RavenDB uses Newtonsoft JSON.Net library for serialization.  You can [read more here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationAttributes.htm).  Basically, it honors the [DataMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574795) from .net, which is used in conjunction with the [DataContractAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585243) - both of which where originally designed for XML serialization in WCF.  But their behavior carries forward into JSON.Net if you still use them.

Comment: BTW - that is the default and expected behavior when you use those attributes on anything.  You can read more in the remarks sections of those MSDN links.

Comment: Thanks, @MattJohnson. What about a case where you want to send a property across the wire (requiring the attribute), but you don't want to persist it in RavenDB? Is this when you'd use the JsonIgnore attribute?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it.  Be sure to import from `Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json` namespace.  A better way would be to use a separate object for storage than for data transfer, such as commonly called a DTO (Data Transfer Object)